# Is the size of my /var/lib/dpkg/info too big?

Tags: dpkg, directory

I was looking for something, and came upon   `/var/lib/dpkg/info`  , with

```
Contents: 15,628 items, totalling 82.6 MB.
```

Is this too big?

Comment: 82.6 MB seems okay; mine is 109 MB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/var/lib/dpkg/info` contains files that relate to packages - including the list of files (as full path names) provided by each package, the MD5sums of each of these files, and the executable scripts that would be run before and after installation or removal (preinst, postinst, prerm, postrm). Of course the system contains many, many packages and each one has multiple files here.

The more packages you install, the bigger this directory will get.

**This directory is really important to the system. You should never delete anything from it, and if you do, you can expect bad bad bad things to occur.**

size of my `/var/lib/dpkg/info` on a recently installed system:

```
74200 files, 41.8 MB
```

Conclusion: 80 MB is a normal size for this directory. Leave it alone :)

See [Chapter 2](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html) of the Debian Reference for detailed information.