# Fix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 for libpaper1:amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

After trying to configure some packages I am getting an error for the libpaper1:amd64 package.

Error :

```
Setting up libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.28) ...
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpaper1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpaper1:amd6
```

System info :

```
Linux user-Vostro-3590 5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I resolve this issue?
So far I've tried purging/reinstalling/reconfiguring but the error still persists.

Edit: I tried to figure out the error in the post-installation script. This is what I got

```
sh -x libpaper1:amd64.postinst configure 1.1.28
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ !  ]
+ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
+ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
+ [  ]
+ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend libpaper1:amd64.postinst configure 1.1.28
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
Can't exec "libpaper1:amd64.config": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.28/IPC/Open3.pm line 178.
open2: exec of libpaper1:amd64.config configure 1.1.28 failed: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59.
```

I have no idea how to debug this error. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to include what package/program you are trying to install

Comment: @user535733 I dont have much idea about how to fix the post-installation script. Can you guide me towards that ?

Comment: I was able to open the post-installation script. How should I go about debugging it ?

Comment: Had this happen with timidity-daemon. [yeh](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258104/22949)'s answer saved me a headache

Answer (score 38):

I just had the same issue and here's what I did to fix it...

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpaper1*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 libpaper1
sudo apt -f install
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for contributing. When you post an answer like this, it's very helpful to describe what the commands are doing and why they will fix the problem. This helps prevent people blindly running commands without understanding them and getting themselves in trouble. It also help people develop a sense of how to solve problems themselves.

Comment: [This answer about the dpkg/info directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805476/is-the-size-of-my-var-lib-dpkg-info-too-big), which seems to be more detailed and informed, warns against deleting things from this directory, or "you can expect bad bad bad things to occur". I'm a bit reluctant to try this.

Comment: Also, better than deleting with "sudo rm..." would be to just move the files eg. "sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpaper1* ~/backup". So if anything goes south, you can restore the data. On prod servers I learned its better to move data at first and deleting if everything works fine ;-)

Comment: Just want to say THANK YOU SO MUCH to  yeh and Eliah / Toby in the related answer below - you FIXED my problem with the messy Brave Browser,  which refuses to de-install properly on Linux.   I just *lost most of a morning*  to this headache and the advice (below version specifically)  SORTED this fully for me.  Looks like some 'central dpkg' wisdom in this, in fact.   Thanks again MH London

Answer (score 15):

Oh, nice, [yeh's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258104/22949) worked wonders. I had the same problem with the Brave browser package.

Just changed:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpaper1*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 libpaper1
sudo apt -f install
```

To:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/*brave-browser*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 com.brave.brave-browser
sudo apt -f install
```

The same applies for every other package, just put the right name in.

Comment: [ as noted above] I Just want to say THANK YOU SO MUCH to  yeh (above)  and Eliah / Toby  for this answer  - you FIXED my problem with the messy Brave Browser,  which refuses to de-install properly on Linux.   I just *lost most of a morning*  to this headache,  and the advice (below version specifically)  SORTED this fully for me.  Looks like some 'central dpkg' wisdom in this, in fact.   Thanks again MH London

Comment: This is the only thing that fixed my issue after days of trying things out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt reinstall libpaper1
```

is what solved the issue for me.