# error in sysstat

Tags: dpkg

When I try to update any thing I got an error from sysstat with code 10.
tried to uninstall, fix-broken, and install sysstat, I got this error:

```
(Reading database ... 222155 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sysstat_12.5.2-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sysstat (12.5.2-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up sysstat (12.5.2-2ubuntu0.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package sysstat (--configure):
 installed sysstat package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sysstat
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exactly same error like yours. And the command provided by [yeh's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258104/1085627) works well in this case.

I changed the package name so the command works for `sysstat`:

```bash
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/sysstatbkinfo
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/sysstat* /var/lib/dpkg/sysstatbkinfo/
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 sysstat
sudo apt install -f
```

These lines remove the existing dpkg info, and reconfigure the package.